# MySQL on udp port

Tags: mysql

I have searched around on the internet but could not find any satisfying answer. Can someone please guide, here are my confusions/questions.

1. Can we run mysql on udp port instead of default tcp port?
2. If running mysql on udp is possible, what are pros and cons?

Comment: A database really doesn't suit UDP very well. What happens if you have packet loss? If packets arrive out of order? Your data will be jumbled and non-retransmissable. Bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to run MySQL on UDP port, or using ICMP informational messages. Just because of it's design - it's a TCP application. To run it on UDP port it has to be rewritten in it's network part from scratch, to use UDP instead of TCP, which it's using now. Since it's opensource, it's pretty doable, but nobody so far have tried it. Mostly because nobody needs to run it on UDP.

Comment: I would not say it was written with TCP in mind. It is  "kind of" message oriented, with message/packet including a sequence number (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/mysql-packet.html ). The packet maximum size is larger than what you can have in UDP (i.e MySQL packet is up to 16MB), however if both the queries and result set row fit into a single UDP packet, it seems to be doable. Of course, correct sequencing of the packets on the receiver side needs to be implemented for that

Comment: I completely agree that this is technically achievable.